# Since rainbow isn't a "thing" why does it have a specific position, or why does it look like you're approaching it if you're moving in a car?

Tags: visible-light, refraction

Since a rainbow is wrt to the observer but all drops refract the light, why don't people see it at different places in the sky? Is it because the difference in angle is negligible.

Comment: how about this https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Optics/Book%3A_Geometric_Optics_(Tatum)/01%3A_Reflection_and_Refraction/1.07%3A_The_Rainbow

Comment: "Since a rainbow is wrt to the observer" I think it depends on the sun, not the obsetver. The observer observes it as one observes an image, from different directions.

Comment: Ooh I think that would make more sense. The angle wrt the sun is constant then?

Comment: But then shouldn't it be visible only at a very narrow position where the angles are such that the light directly reaches the eye

Comment: The sun according to the formulae makes the bow, a shape  that reflects in all directions, from thousands and millions of drops there is no narrowness except the angular definitions  limit it

Comment: I see, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

A rainbow might look like it has a specific position, but actually its apparent location/angle moves gradually as you move. Notice that you've never seen a rainbow from an angle; it's always just about perpendicular to you. If the location were constant that wouldn't be the case and you could really find the pot of gold at the end of the rainbow.

Another thing to notice is that an apparent object doesn't have to be real to have an apparent location. In a mirror, your reflected self has a location (which all viewers of the mirror WOULD agree on), yet behind the mirror there is actually nothing there. Computer screens displaying a photograph are another example.

Comment: That's true. Why can different people slightly away from each other point out to the rainbow being in a specific part of the sky? As if it were to the right of A and Left of B...

Comment: The light from the rainbow comes from the sun, hits water droplets in the air, and then comes to you and your friend. The location of the water droplets which show the rainbow that you see are such that the sunlight hits the water droplet and then continues on to you. The color of the light after leaving the droplet depends on the angle at which the light was reflected, so you only see red from a certain angle for example. And you only see blue from another angle. And the angle your friend makes  with those drops is not that different from your own angle. So you see it in a similar place.

Comment: I get it now, thank you so much!